# Xcode 7.3.1 Builds Correctly but fails on Archive

Tags: swift, xcode7, building, archiving

Hi I am having an issue archiving.

I have the following in my bridging header

```
#import <AWSDK/AWController.h>
#import <AWSDK/AWSDKCore.h>
```

yet it gives me the following archiving problem

[image]

Yet it builds correctly and deploys to my phone.

can anyone help me out here? I have been stuck on this for a few days.

Comment: Build and run on your phone, using Xcode, is a Debug build. Archive is a Release build. Your build settings for Release build must be incorrect in some way.

Comment: You are right, I changed my run to release, and it fails on build. Keep in mind I use cocoapods so do you know where I would look to begin to solve this problem?

Comment: Good work. - Suppose your pod config says `pod 'MyPod', :configurations => ['Debug']`, then it isn't going to be included in your release build.